# Using VLookup to find corresponding row

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have 5 sheets in an excel file named

- roll 1to2.5
- roll2.5to5
- roll5to7
- roll 7to9.5
- roll 9.5to12

Each sheet has two columns with the following data:

```
A  B
1  22
2  25
3  29
4  20
5  18
6  26
7  19
8  16
9  21
10 20
```

Now I have been able to do the following: In column C, if I enter a number from Col A, say "7", i get the corresponding value from Col B i.e. "19". I used the following formula

```
=VLOOKUP(C5,A1:B10,2,FALSE)
```

This works good uptill here.

**Issue 1:** Let's say I want to enter the roll in a cell say "5.5", it should automatically consider data from sheet 3 (roll5to7)

**Issue 2:** and then if I enter a value of ColB, say "20", it should pick up the corresponding value from ColA i.e. "4" (first match) in sheet 3.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @pnuts How do I change the formula to include INDEX, MATCH http://www17.zippyshare.com/v/24524609/file.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the right sheet name list your 5 sheet names in one column and in the **previous** column the lower bound for each (1, 2.5, 5, 7 and 9) and name that two column table **Table**

Now you can use this formula

`=VLOOKUP(C5,INDIRECT("'"&LOOKUP(D5,Table)&"'!A1:B10"),2,FALSE)`

where D5 contains the roll

`LOOKUP` finds the correct sheet name and `INDIRECT` converts text to a valid reference

**Edit:**

If you want to look for C5 in column B and find the corresponding value from column A then `INDEX/MATCH` would look like this:

`=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&LOOKUP(D5,Table)&"'!A1:A10"),MATCH(C5,INDIRECT("'"&LOOKUP(D5,Table)&"'!B1:B10"),0))`

Comment: Thanks Barry. I am missing something obvious. I have tried your example. With your code, when ColA value is given it returns ColB value. But I want when ColB value is given, return ColA value. http://www17.zippyshare.com/v/24524609/file.html

Comment: @pnuts suggested to use Index, Match for Req 2. How do I change the formula?

Comment: OK, I edited my answer - the INDEX/MATCH version still uses D5 to determine which sheet to use but the looks up C5 in B1:B10 and finds the corresponding value from A1:A10

Comment: Can you look into this too. Nobody seems to know how it is done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110807/querying-data-in-one-excel-sheet-from-another